# Using regex how do I match a string that only contains one space

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list of strings:

1. John Cena
2. Anya Taylor-Joy
3. D'Angelo
4. john cena
5. J0hn C3na
6. John   Cena

**I want to match the following patterns:**
does not match a lowercase string,
does not match a string containing numbers,
does not match a string containing non-single-space whitespace sequences.

```
[A-Z] ([a-z\-'].*)
```

This pattern matches everything but lines 4 and 5 which is good, but I need it to also not match line 6 which contains more than one whitespaces sequence.

I've tried variations of

```
[A-Z](\s[a-z\-'].*)  and [A-Z]([ ][a-z\-'].*)
```

But I cannot get it to work.

Comment: `[A-Z] ([a-z\-'].*)` does not match any of the provided lines. Should the regex support all Unicode letters? What is the expected result for the given strings?

Comment: You can try: `^[A-Z][-A-Za-z']*(?: [-A-Z-a-z']+)?$`

Comment: @anubhava I doubt [that regex](https://regex101.com/r/E1e2rJ/1) will help: it does not match my name, and matches some rubbish.

Comment: Your string #6 does not contain more than one whitespace.  You should use quotes in your examples to ensure that we see the white spaces you're referring to.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work by doing the following pattern:

^[A-Z][A-z-']+[ ]?[A-z-']+

Comment: `A-z` is most probably wrong (it will match all character that are between ASCII `A` and ASCII `z`, which includes e.g. `[]`); you want `A-Za-z` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a lookahead to ensure that there is at least one capital letter (i.e. string is not all lowercase). Then check for a sequence of one or more valid letters/characters followed by an optional space and a second sequence of valid characters:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])[^0-9 ]+( [^0-9 ]+)?$
```

I suspect however that your criteria is actually a bit more specific.  If you are trying to extract first name and last name that are both capitalized, then the "non-lowercase" condition should be expressed as non-capitalized words.  In that case, the pattern wouldn't need the lookahead:

```
^[A-Z][^0-9 ]*( [A-Z][^0-9 ]*)?$
```

this would not match "John cena" for example.